# Java/SpringBoot/SQL : get accumulation

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring-data-jpa

I have an object call usages with those attributes : String resourceName, int work, int cost, LocalDate date, int weekOfYear, Month month, String quarter, Integer year, int scenarioId.

I m trying to get the accumulation of work order by date and group by date. I found a request which work in MySqlWorkbench but when i try it with repository and controller i get just the object without accumulation.

Here my request on MysqlWorkbench :

```
SELECT *, @sum := (@sum + work) AS cumulative_work
FROM table.usages
WHERE scenario_id=:scenario_id
JOIN (SELECT @sum := 0) r 
ORDER BY date;
```

Here on my repository what I tried:

```
@Query  (value="SELECT *, @sum\\:=(@sum + work) AS cumulative_work\n" + 
            "FROM table.usages\n" + 
            "JOIN (SELECT @sum\\:=0) r \n" + 
            "where scenario_id=:scenario_id\n" + 
            "ORDER BY date;", nativeQuery=true)
Collection<? extends Usage> cumulOfWork(@Param("scenario_id")Long scenarioId);
```

Thanks a lot in advance,

Comment: Why is that method declared twice?

Comment: Is there a typo in `**@Query    (value="SELECT cumulative_work, @sum\\:=(@sum + work) AS cumulative_work\n"`; looks like it has `cumulative_work` twice.

Comment: Even by not having twice I can't get the accumulation throught spring boot! The request works well on MysqlWorkbench :)